# Архитектура сервера небольшого телеканала

Tags: сервер, администрирование

Интересует Linux сервер или другая производительная система + файловая система с подключенным к серверу i-Stor iS16S6S6 c JBOD обьемом на 116 терабайт, часть сервера используется для хранения и монтирования на 5 одновременно работающих монтажных станциях (MacOS Maverick + пакет Adobe)

Требуется максимальная скорость работы и разграничение прав :

- монтажеры
- редаторы
- архивисты

Плюс какая-то защита от потерь/удалений.

Сейчас файловая система HFS+ через SAS сервер MacOS Xserver 10.6 - старенький уже

Хотелось бы **увеличения скорости**, **надежности**, **возможности восстановления**.

Особенно интересует Linux, знаком с дистрибутивами Debian(Ubuntu, Mint) и OpenSUSE

**Какие архитектурные решения вы бы порекомендовали для такой задачи?**

Comment: Можно уточнить? вам и железо и софт нужно или одно из двух??

Comment: И какой бюджет на все?

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую [Btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page#Major_Features_Currently_Implemented).

- Создание снэпшотов (для бэкапа) мгновенно, альтернатива LVM.
- Поддержка множества дисков, [альтернатива RAID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254286/does-it-make-sense-to-put-btrfs-on-lvm).
- Дедупликация (на случай, если кто-то гигабайты копирует). Кстати, копировать можно мгновенно 'cp --reflink'
- онлайн дефрагментация
- поддерживает сжатие данных
- квоты
- и т.п.

Выбор дистрибутива большого значения не имеет, однако, [SUSE нельзя скачать](http://specialmeaning.blogspot.com/2015/11/opensuse.html) безопасно.

Answer (score 1):

Как человек непосредственно имеющий отношение к ТВ, в том числе и к постпродакшену, скажу сразу, если OSX то смотри в сторону SAN и XSAN в частности, если контора толерантна к eBay там можно недорого купить фибровые адаптеры ATTO и какой-нибудь SAN свитч типа QLogic Sanbox 5600, для редакторов и т.д. шарить через SMB.
Как пример,
1 - два Mac Pro как контроллеры XSAN (с резервом)
2 - Один свитч QLogic SanBox 5600 (если брать б/у надо смотреть сколько портов открыто, если не докупали лицензию то из 16 портов будет открыто 8, в принципе хватит если на заморачиваться с подключением по двум FC каналам )
3 - ATTO Celerity FC-42ES или FC-41ES по одной на каждую монтажку + по одной в каждый контролер XSAN
4- ну и ещё нужна мелочёвка в виде оптических патчей и гбиков

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал собрать файловый сервер на основе какого-нибудь HP DL160, воткнув в него SAS-контроллер и подключив iStor. Единственное "но" по этому железу — будет ли достаточно двух гигабитных интерфейсов в режиме транка. Если нет, то придётся смотреть на что-то более объёмистое (DL180?), потому что ещё и десятигигабитную плату в DL160 уже, скорее всего, не воткнуть. При выборе конкретного железа берите то, у которого больше RAM (48G и больше) и CPU (2 x quadcore).

Софт — Debian. Файловая система — наверное XFS, доступ традиционный, через samba. С разделением прав проблем возникнуть не должно.

Это что касается увеличения скорости. С надёжностью, мне кажется, у вас и так всё хорошо.

Вся радость при покупке через eBay должна вписаться в ~250-350 долларов, не считая транспортировки. Если ещё дополнительно потратите долларов восемьсот-тысячу на LTO-5 накопитель, то появится возможность хранения оффлайн-бэкапов для возможности восстановления. Ну или рассмотрите возможность использования снапшотов LVM, места достаточно, судя по всему.